# How can I debug a FTP connection loss?

Tags: networking, ftp, connection

I need a little bit help. Currently I have a server in a datacenter and an FTP Server in another that I use to backup files. My problem is that some times the connection just got lost. It may happen after 20 Minutes or after some hours. The provider of the FTP Server says that the fault is on my side. So how can I prove what is really happening? Because I think that their server is just overloaded.

One Idea is to use tcpdump but…. As I said, it sometimes happens after 20 Minutes and sometimes after hours. And we are talking about gigabytes of data that are transferred during this period of time. Maybe you have a better idea.

Comment: tcpdump can do circular captures. Most issues like this usually require a correlated capture.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Wireshark would be your best bet. Run wireshark on both ends or on the client side. Let it run in the background. When you check next time, filter the packets with FTP and its failures and you can easily see what is the response of the server side for connection loss and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

there is no simple answer for issues like connection lost with no obvious pattern .
network stats,  iostat,  cpu usage ,etc are the common starting point.

you  want to start from convincing yourself the server is not overloaded.

write a small script collecting stats above every 10 or 15 seconds，find any unusual pattern that is around connection losing point.

again , no simple answer for issues like this.